# Resetting the database using Cypress (postgresql)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, postgresql, next.js, cypress

When I populate the database, I don't do it completely (for certain tests I chose to populate only when I get to them). In the end, I would like to reset the database, so that when I do the next populate (the next tests running), the database will be reset so that complications do not appear. How could I reset this database after running all tests (all specs)?

What I tried to do was to use the "after" hook with the "npx prisma migrate reset --force" command, but that resets the database after each file, not after all the specs have run.

One option would be to make a file in which to import all the test files, and when I run the file with all the imports, in the end, reset the database. The minus in this version is that every time I add a new test I have to include it in the imports from this file.

What would be the best practice?

Answer (score 1):

If you have something that works in the `after()` hook, try moving it to the [After Run API](https://docs.cypress.io/api/plugins/after-run-api#Syntax) which is kind-of a hook, but as it says executes after the run.

Here's the basic shell from the docs:

```js
const { defineConfig } = require('cypress')

module.exports = defineConfig({
  // setupNodeEvents can be defined in either
  // the e2e or component configuration
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      on('after:run', (results) => {
        /* ... */
      })
    }
  }
})
```

One thing you should do after implementing is deliberately fail a test and see if the database is cleared. Some `after()` type hooks don't run in a fail scenario.

If you find that to be the case, instead add a `before()` at the top of the `cypress/support/e2e.js` file so that the database is cleared before each run.

Also, importing your setup functions there can save you importing them into each spec.

Comment: "If you have something that works in the after() hook, try moving it to the After Run API which is kind-of a hook, but as it says executes after the run." --> the problem is I cannot call Cypress or cy commands in this function and my database resetting includes cy command.

Comment: It would be nice to see that detail in the question, or is it secret?